# Get latest change of variable according to a timestamp

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following data:

```
data have;
   input username $  betdate : datetime. customerCode;
   dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
   format betdate DATETIME.;
   format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
   datalines; 
    player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 1
    player1 04NOV2008:09:03:44 10
    player2 07NOV2008:07:03:33 1 
    player2 05NOV2008:09:00:00 0.5 
    player3 05NOV2008:09:05:00 1
    player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 1 
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:05 20
    player2 07NOV2008:16:03:33 1 
    player2 07NOV2008:18:03:33 1 
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:10 0.7
    player3 15NOV2008:15:05:33 10 
    player3 15NOV2008:15:05:33 1
    player2 15NOV2008:15:05:33 0.1
run;
PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

How can I run a 'proc sql' command to pull out each player's latest (i.e. the distinct(customerCode) with the latest date (i.e: max(betdate) and each player's earliest (by betdate again) update for customerCode? This is a dynamic variable that's changing from time to time? Do I have to run a subselect for each username, looking for the max(betdate) and customerCode from the table?

Thanks.

Comment: Added SQL tag so you might get better responses from SQL experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROC SQL isn't the easiest way to do it, but it's certainly possible.

```
proc sql;
 select H.username, H.customercode from have H inner join (
  select username, max(betdate) as maxdate from have group by username
 ) V
 on H.username=V.username and H.betdate=V.maxdate;
quit;
```

That returns two values for Player3, you would have to work out how to resolve ties.  Data step is much easier though, requiring at most one sort and one pass (and in a hash would be even faster, or in an IML matrix).

Comment: That works fine. The observation with the duplicate betdate for player3 above was a typo on my part, so I've changed it. I'm trying to replicate your code with a subselect rather than an innerjoin, as follows, because this will make it easier to pull out the first and last values for customerCode for example, but it won't evaluate to a singele row per player! `proc sql;
 select H.username, (select V.customercode from have V where V.username = H.username and V.betdate = 
 (Select max(X.betdate) from have X where X.username = H.username))
 from have H group by username;
quit;`

Comment: That won't resolve down to one if you have ties, as I noted - you need to figure out some way to resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a feature of `proc sql` known as aggregation with "remerging".  The following query outputs every row with the max date by username:

```
proc sql;
 select H.username, H.customercode, date, max(date) as maxdate
 from have H 
 group by H.username
quit;
```

You can then put this in a subquery to get the values you want:

```
proc sql;
 select username, customercode, date
 from (select H.username, H.customercode, date, max(date) as maxdate
       from have h
       group by H.username
      ) h
 where date = maxdate;
quit;
```

The following may also work, but I don't have SAS on hand to test where I am now:

```
proc sql;
  select H.username, H.customercode, date
  from have H 
  group by H.username
  having date = max(date)
quit;
```

Comment: One note - remerging is basically SAS-only, I don't know of any other SQL flavors that will allow you to get this automatic merge (or allow you to select things not in the group by or aggregate functions).

Comment: @Joe . . . The first part of your statement is true (this is one of many differences between `proc sql` and other SQL dialects).  The second part is not true.  MySQL support columns not in the `group by` clause, as do some versions of Postgres.  This functionality is even consistent with the more recent versions of the ANSI standard (although the result is quite different from what `proc SQL` produces).

Comment: Well, I only know/use SQL Server and Oracle, so it was technically true ;)  Thanks for the clarification, though.